# should I avoid using retf?

Tags: linux, function, assembly, x86, return

I learnt that when we use `retn`, `ip` will be popped. When `retf` used `cs`, `ip` will be popped.

My question is: A procedure can't know where it is called from (don't know whether `call near` or `call far` is used), so when we use `call far func`, but `func` end up with `ret` the `cs` is left in stack.

On the other hand, when we use `call func` with `func` end up with `retf`, the wrong `cs` is popped. How to  solved the problem? Should I avoid using `retf` (avoid calling a procedure in another segment)?

```
[section A]
....
call dword func ; call func in section B

[section B]
....
call func
func:
      ....
      ret   ; in section B,use "call func", so ret is OK,
            ; but in section A, use call dword, push cs,ip, but only ip popped
```

Comment: Which CPU architecture and which OS?

Comment: Your post is not really understandable. Maybe you could show it to someone proficient in English?

Comment: And which OS? Linux, Windows, something else, what?

Comment: Linux,Actually I am wondering is there any difference when I use nasm to generate .bin files on different OS :)

Comment: Actually, a function *has* to know whether it will be called near or far, for precisely this reason. A commonly used rule these days is everything you ever see is near (far calls/rets/jumps are still around, but typically not in code that you write).

Answer (score 1):

Typically this is handled by the assembler.  You declare a procedure NEAR or FAR and the assembler codes the call/ret appropriately.  If you choose to misuse it (such as forcing a far call to near procedure), bad things will happen.  Don't let bad things happen.  :-)

Comment: Well,do you mean that we should simply use call and ret,and let the assembler do the left work?

Comment: Another question,thanks,Just like the code above,assembler can change the 'ret' to 'retf' when section A calls func,and the 'ret' to 'retn' when section B calls func?If so,how can assembler achieve this?

Comment: It can't change the retn to a retf on the fly.  You need to declare func as either PROC NEAR or PROC FAR and then the assembler will call it the right way from each reference (as long as it's in scope).

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, all flavors of Linux on x86 use a flat 32- or 64-bit memory model - segment registers CS/DS have a constant value (most likely zero) and never change. With this in mind, `FAR` operations are never necessary - neither `call far`, nor `retf`. Don't use them on Linux.

For the same reason, Linux uses 32-bit or 64-bit registers. It's EIP/RIP, not IP.

The only (once) prominent platforms where segments were used nontrivially were MS-DOS and Win16.

Comment: Doesn't 64bit linux use cs in a similar way as win64? (flat model, but the value in `cs` determines the bitness)

Comment: Not sure, but even if it does, calls within a single compilation unit have no business switching bitness. It's a flat model for userland purposes.

Comment: All right I found this: http://www.x86-64.org/pipermail/discuss/2004-August/005020.html that clears it up I guess. Just to satisfy my curiosity of course.

Comment: In deed there are some 32-bit OSs (not Windows and not Linux) that use far memory layouts. CS contains some information in all x86 OSs but normally function calls in the 32-bit world are typically only near calls (pushing EIP only) because these OSs use flat memory layout where only one value for CS is used.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev doesn't matter. The point is, the picture you're painting is a little too simple. Far call/jump/etc is only gone from normal code, not gone entirely.

Comment: @harold: you're right, but that's also irrelevant to the question. The OP is very clearly not looking for advanced techniques like dynamic bitness. He/she obviously read some DOS-era manual, with segment registers featured prominently, and needs to be told about Linux' flat model.